# How to pass data from a VueJS component to main.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, state-management

Is it possible to send data defined in a component in the data() method to the main.js file (or where the Vue instance is defined)? I thought I could use vueX to do the following but have no idea as how to approach it even after understanding computed props, getters and mutations:

```
Data in Component -> Store -> Main.js
```

---

**EDIT: HOW DO I SET DATA IN THE VUEX STORE FROM THE COMP?**

Imagine the store has a property called currentList, whose values need to be fed in from a list in Component1.vue. How would I send that list to the VueX Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data from your component to the Vuex $store, you should use Mutations (or actions, if the data comes into your component asynchronously).

Assuming your mutation has already been defined in the store (and the store has been set up correctly), you can call it from your component as follows:

> this.$store.commit("YOUR_MUTATION", "data")

I do recommend the vue-tools in your browser to keep track of what's in your store.

Answer (score 1):

I know no Vue, but I believe I understood what you're looking for.
What you're trying to achieve here, in every other front-end framework, can be called like: "component to parent communication".

You can have a 4th level nested component and you want to pass some data to the Main.js (that I suppose, in Vue, it's still a component, precisely the root one)

As I see, you can use $emit: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201
In React (and you can do this in Vue too, but you should choose the vue style solution) you would use a callback function: the parent pass to the child a function that the child can call to set a certain property inside the parent comp.

Another common option nowadays, that avoids completely this kind of communication, is the use of a state management lib like Redux. In that every component can access a global store (that is like a global variable) and after the 4th level component set a property in this global store, the main.js can read it.

Comment: VueX is a global state solution for VueJS. I just don't know how to modify data in the store from the component, I can send the store data to another component just fine.

Comment: committing a mutation as you can see in the vuex doc :) https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html